# Interactive flash content on iOS

Tags: ios, flash, air, ffmpeg

I want to play interactive (user inputs/actions) flash contents-videos on the iOS devices. I am having flv files in which user can have their inputs like option selection, page turn etc.

I am having 2 approach about the functionality. Please correct if I am wrong.

**1.Adobe-air can be used on the iPad devices. Does it have the ability to parse flash content run time? (use flash content as resources/bundle)**

**2.With the help of FFMPEG lib flash files/videos will work, but will it provide user actions/interactions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No to both. Adobe Air can only be used to create applications. You can't actually play flash files using it. FFMPEG will only play flash videos, it will not allow interaction.

Basically, if you have flash interactive content that you want to display on the iPhone you are going to have to think of a different way to present it.

Comment: You might be able to extract flash resources from .flv files, but I see no reason for doing so.

Comment: Run time parsing of flash content is now possible if you include your content when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Since air 3.8 it got much more easier to run swf content from ios - but it is a pain if your content is external yes...

Also I was able to play dynamic video using starling and flv in the background at 12fps on ipod and 24fps on iphones and ipads.

The key there is how you upload the bitmapData to the GPU:

```
flash.display3D.textures.Texture(videoLayer.texture.base).uploadFromBitmapData(bitmapData);
```

Where *videoLayer* is a Starling Image and **bitmapData** is a drawn bitmapData from the video.

The rest of the code is trivial stuff that you can find easily online, but the Texture.uploadFromBitmapData is what really made a performance difference.

See it in action in the app store: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id723967141?mt=8